# What is the purpose of left shifting zero by any amount?

Tags: java

Upon reading the ASM 4.1 source code I've found instances of the following:

```
int ASM4 = 4 << 16 | 0 << 8 | 0;
int ASM5 = 5 << 16 | 0 << 8 | 0;
```

Does these left shifts of zero by 8 do anything to the expression, or the 'or' by 0 for that matter?

Wouldn't it be equivalent to just have:

```
int ASM4 = 4 << 16;
int ASM5 = 5 << 16;
```

Comment: shifting zero will result in 0 ...

Comment: testing for the equivalence is easy: https://ideone.com/NabSvO

Comment: Maybe it's some boiler plate that happens to be zero here? Easy to change to something else as is.

Comment: What's the point of shifting a constant? Might as well write `int ASM4 = 262144;` (The answer to this question is the same as the answer to that question)

Comment: @immibis it's easier to see where the number came from if you use the shift. I wouldn't recognise 262144 as 4^16 (or even 2^18).

Comment: Highly recommended to use parentheses. How much would you be willing to bet a million dollars that << has higher priority than | ?

Comment: The compiler will calculate a constant of any of those. You can go on by adding 0 and multiply by 1. These are all neutral operations.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Indeed they are equivalent but one possible explanation is that they wanted to map the version numbers including both the *major* and *minor* numbers to a unique ID in their code. So in the following:

```
int ASM4 = 4 << 16 | 0 << 8 | 0; // this looks like 4.0.0
int ASM5 = 5 << 16 | 0 << 8 | 0; // this looks list 5.0.0
```

The `4` and `5` represent versions `4` and `5` respectively, and the `zero` in `0 << 8` could potentially be the minor numbers, and the last `zero` is another minor number, as in `4.0.0` and `5.0.0`. But that's my guess anyway. You'd really have to ask the authors.

Comment: +1: a program is written not only for a computer to compile, but for the next developer to read.  In fact, I find programs more and more are written for the next developer to read, with a little dash of syntax here and there to make it compile.  Large programs are hard to read!

Comment: +1 but ... It's all very well and good until someone decides to make `<< inside | should have parentheses` a compiler warning... :-(

Comment: int ASM4 = 0x400;

would have accomplished the same purpose a little more concisely..

Comment: @pericynthion: Maybe the same purpose, but to get the identical effect you'd have to write `int ASM4 = 0x40000` which IMHO makes it less obvious that this corresponds to version 4.0.0.  (And maybe they wanted to allow for version 4.0.16...)

Comment: @NateEldredge Indeed. I like that 5 people +1ed my comment, all of whom evidently can't remember how many bits are in a nibble any more than I can!

Comment: @NateEldredge: That's why we're getting `0x4'00'00`

Answer (score 17):

In context:

```
// ASM API versions

int ASM4 = 4 << 16 | 0 << 8 | 0;
int ASM5 = 5 << 16 | 0 << 8 | 0;
```

Yes, this is equivalent to

```
int ASM4 = 4 << 16;
int ASM5 = 5 << 16;
```

This is just written that way to make it clear that we are setting the 3rd byte to 4, and both lower bytes to 0. Alternatively, that it is a version number that should be read as 4.0.0.

Comment: Interesting how it sometimes works on SO. You said pretty much the same as the accepted answer, and posted it even a little *earlier*.

Comment: I had to read this answer to the last sentence to get the point. Then i noticed the grey-on-grey comment line hinted at the answer.

Answer (score 10):

It indeed serves no purpose, but then it is neatly and visually aligned so that the ASM developers know about the opcodes versions (if I'm not mistaken, this is the `OpCodes` interface you're looking at here).

The same way that you'd use `1 << 0` vs `1 << 1`, etc.

Comment: I wonder if they've heard of commenting? Either way, this seems like the most likely explanation.

Comment: @christopher even if they did, well, as the saying goes, code talks ;)

Comment: @christopher This is pretty standard in embedded development.  If you're setting bits for any reason (eg, driving a peripheral), it's important to be clear that you're explicitly writing a zero rather than just forgetting that the particular bit is relevant.